# Saving list of objects locally on device with shared_preferences in Flutter

Tags: json, flutter, flutter-sharedpreference

I created an app that can send IR signals in which you can add IR signals yourself. The signals are saved in an object list named Item with items as the objects. I want the names and signals saved locally on the device with the application running but the items are never saved: Here is the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:ir_sensor_plugin/ir_sensor_plugin.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

class Item {
  String buttonName = "", hexCode = "";
  bool isSelected = false;

  Item({
    required this.buttonName,
    required this.hexCode,
  });

  // Method to convert the Item object to a JSON object
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'buttonName': buttonName,
      'hexCode': hexCode,
      'isSelected': isSelected,
    };
  }

  // Method to convert a JSON object to an Item object
  static Item fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Item(
      buttonName: json['buttonName'],
      hexCode: json['hexCode'],
    );
  }
}

class IrRemoteEmulator extends StatefulWidget {
  const IrRemoteEmulator({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<IrRemoteEmulator> createState() => _IrRemoteEmulatorState();
}

class _IrRemoteEmulatorState extends State<IrRemoteEmulator> {
  String buttonName = "";
  TextEditingController _buttonName = TextEditingController();
  String hexCode = "";
  TextEditingController _hexCode = TextEditingController();

  List<Item> items = [
    Item(
        buttonName: "Samsung Power",
        hexCode:
            "0000 006d 0022 0003 00a9 00a8 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 003f 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0040 0015 0015 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 0702 00a9 00a8 0015 0015 0015 0e6e"),
    Item(
        buttonName: "Prowise Power",
        hexCode:
            "0000 006d 0022 0003 00a9 00a8 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 003f 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0040 0015 0015 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 0702 00a9 00a8 0015 0015 0015 0e6e")
  ];

  // Method to save the items list to the local storage
  Future<void> saveList(List<Item> items) async {
    // Get the instance of the shared preferences
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    // Convert the items list to a JSON string
    var itemsJson = json.encode(items);

    // Save the JSON string to the local storage
    prefs.setString('items', itemsJson);
    debugPrint("Items saved");
  }

  Future<List<Item>> loadList() async {
    // Get the instance of the shared preferences
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    // Retrieve the JSON string from the local storage
    var itemsJson = prefs.getString('items') ?? '';

    // Convert the JSON string to a List<Item> object
    var items = json.decode(itemsJson);
    debugPrint("Items loaded");
    return items;
  }

  String selectedHexcode =
      "0000 006d 0022 0003 00a9 00a8 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 003f 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0040 0015 0015 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 0702 00a9 00a8 0015 0015 0015 0e6e";

  String _platformVersion = 'Unkown';
  bool _hasIrEmitter = false;
  String _getCarrierFrequencies = 'Unknown';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // Load the saved items list from the local storage
    loadList().then((savedItems) {
      // Set the items list to the loaded list
      setState(() {
        items = savedItems;
      });
    });

    initPlatformState();
  }

  // Platform messages are asynchronous, so we initialize in an async method.
  Future<void> initPlatformState() async {
    String platformVersion;
    bool hasIrEmitter;
    String getCarrierFrequencies;

    // Platform messages may fail, so we use a try/catch PlatformException.
    try {
      platformVersion = await IrSensorPlugin.platformVersion;
      hasIrEmitter = await IrSensorPlugin.hasIrEmitter;
      getCarrierFrequencies = await IrSensorPlugin.getCarrierFrequencies;
    } on PlatformException {
      platformVersion = 'Failed to get data in a platform.';
      hasIrEmitter = false;
      getCarrierFrequencies = 'None';
    }

    // If the widget was removed from the tree while the asynchronous platform
    // message was in flight, we want to discard the reply rather than calling
    // setState to update our non-existent appearance.
    if (!mounted) return;

    setState(() {
      _platformVersion = platformVersion;
      _hasIrEmitter = hasIrEmitter;
      _getCarrierFrequencies = getCarrierFrequencies;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              const SizedBox(
                height: 25,
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 15.0,
              ),
              Container(
                decoration:
                    BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.white)),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      FloatingActionButton.large(
                        onPressed: () async {
                          final String result =
                              await IrSensorPlugin.transmitString(
                                  pattern: selectedHexcode);
                          debugPrint('Emitting  List Int Signal: $result');
                        },
                        child: const Icon(Icons.power_settings_new_outlined),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: SizedBox(
                  height: 200,
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: items.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return ListTile(
                        onTap: () {
                          items[index].isSelected = true;
                          selectedHexcode = items[index].hexCode;
                          debugPrint(items[index].hexCode);
                          setState(() {});
                        },
                        onLongPress: () {
                          items.remove(items[index]);
                          saveList(items);
                          setState(() {});
                        },
                        title: Text(items[index].buttonName),
                        leading: Icon((items[index].hexCode == selectedHexcode)
                            ? Icons.circle
                            : Icons.circle_outlined),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
          onPressed: () => showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
              title: const Text("Add IR Hexcode"),
              content: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  TextFormField(
                    controller: _buttonName,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: "Remotebutton name",
                        hintText: "Ac Powerbutton",
                        hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[300])),
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    controller: _hexCode,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: "Hexcode",
                        hintText:
                            "0000 006d 0022 0003 00a9 00a8 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 003f 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0040 0015 0015 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 0702 00a9 00a8 0015 0015 0015 0e6e",
                        hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[300])),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              actions: [
                TextButton(
                  child: const Text("Cancel"),
                  onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                ),
                TextButton(
                  child: const Text("Ok"),
                  onPressed: () {
                    if (_hexCode.text.isEmpty || _buttonName.text.isEmpty) {
                      debugPrint("${(items.length)}");
                    } else {
                      items.add(Item(
                        buttonName: _buttonName.text,
                        hexCode: _hexCode.text,
                      ));
                      saveList(items);
                      debugPrint("${(items)}");
                    }
                    Navigator.pop(context);

                    setState(() {});
                    return;
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          label: const Text("Add IR Hexcode"),
          icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried adding Shared_preferences but when I had added a new signal and reopened the app, the whole app was reset and I don't see the newly added signal. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

In

```dart
Future<void> saveList(List<Item> items) async {
  // Get the instance of the shared preferences
  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

  // Convert the items list to a JSON string
  var itemsJson = json.encode(items);

  // Save the JSON string to the local storage
  prefs.setString('items', itemsJson);
  debugPrint("Items saved");
}
```

you aren't saving items, you are updating them (because `setString` replace all data that store by key in `SharedPreferences`). And `SharedPreferences` is not a good solution for storing user data (because they designed for storing preferences, it is not a database). For your purposes you need to use a database. If data amount is not large, use [hive](https://pub.dev/packages/hive).